# Untranslated part of the jvm

Tags: java, localization

I stumbled upon the following behavior

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    Locale.setDefault( new Locale( "ar" ));

    System.out.println(new Locale( "ar" ).getDisplayName());
    System.out.println(new Locale( "en" ).getDisplayName());
    System.out.println(new Locale( "fr" ).getDisplayName());
}
```

Output

```
 العربية
 English
 French
```

I stumbled upon the following behavior

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    Locale.setDefault( new Locale( "en" ));

    System.out.println(new Locale( "ar" ).getDisplayName());
    System.out.println(new Locale( "en" ).getDisplayName());
    System.out.println(new Locale( "fr" ).getDisplayName());
}
```

Output

```
 Arabic
 English
 French
```

I stumbled upon the following behavior

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    Locale.setDefault( new Locale( "fr" ));

    System.out.println(new Locale( "ar" ).getDisplayName());
    System.out.println(new Locale( "en" ).getDisplayName());
    System.out.println(new Locale( "fr" ).getDisplayName());
}
```

Output

```
 arabe
 anglais
 français
```

Why there is no traduction for English and French? Does I need to download something else? Can I find a reference for untranslated things like this?

Alexander Campos told me about this web page :
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javase7locales-334809.html

So I executed the following code.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    show("en");
    show("zh_CN");
    show("zh_TW");
    show("fr");
    show("de");
    show("it");
    show("ja");
    show("ko");
    show("pt_BR");
    show("sv");
}

public static void show(String in){
    Locale.setDefault( new Locale( in ) );
    System.out.println(new Locale( "ar" ).getDisplayName());
}
```

Output

```
Arabic
Arabic
Arabic
arabe
Arabisch
arabo
アラビア語
아랍어
Arabic
arabiska
```

So I get that there is only a fraction of the language supported by the jvm and they are documented in the web page. But why am I still getting the default value for zh_CN and zh_TW ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i was doing a little of research of Locale class and take a look fo this:

> public String getDisplayCountry(Locale inLocale)
>
> > Returns a name for the locale's country that is appropriate for
> >     display to the user. If possible, the name returned will be localized
> >     according to inLocale. For example, if the locale is fr_FR and
> >     inLocale is en_US, getDisplayCountry() will return "France"; if the
> >     locale is en_US and inLocale is fr_FR, getDisplayCountry() will return
> >     "Etats-Unis". If the name returned cannot be localized according to
> >     inLocale. (say, we don't have a Japanese name for Croatia), this
> >     function falls back on the English name, and finally on the ISO code
> >     as a last-resort value. If the locale doesn't specify a country, this
> >     function returns the empty string.

Will return the English name.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not exactly what I am looking for. If you dig in the Locale code, you will see that if you do not specifies the Locale, it will take the default one. Also I am talking about language name, and not country name.

Comment: Same thing happens with the lenguaje name. Java dont have all the names for all languages in the locale you specified. Thats why it will return the english name

Comment: Okay. But why? Does it exists additional file that I can add to my deployment? Does a reference about those half-supported language are available? What is not supported my those half-supported language?

Comment: Maybe this help [Java Locales](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javase7locales-334809.html)